# How to know latitude and longitude of the corners of a styled map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

I used the wizard at this link
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html 
to create a styled map with no labels or roads giving the styled map output
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=31.48138,75.801544&zoom=9&format=png&sensor=false&size=640x480&maptype=roadmap&style=feature:road|visibility:off&style=element:labels|visibility:off

Now I wish to know the latitude and longitude of the corners of the static styled map.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can know that from a static map.

Comment: hmm... i was hoping to get the lat long of corners or at least the midpoints of the edges using the center and zoom parameters but i dunno how zoom parameter is linked to the map :(

Comment: To you want to achieve it programmatically(based on the parameters passed to staticmap) or only for this specific map?

Comment: The corners should be calculable.  [The Google Maps Javascript API v3 description of zoom levels and coordinates may help](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#MapCoordinates), I think it is the same as is used for styled maps.  I have seen similar questions before, don't remember where.

Comment: @ Dr.Molle- just for this specific map

Comment: Oh well, in that case you should be able to find that out... Does it need to be exact?

Comment: precision of two decimals is enough

Comment: The bounds are: `((30.917541985971397, 74.92263775000004), (32.0418406658627, 76.68045025000004))`

Comment: Going clockwise from top left corner (NW): (32.03, 74.91), (32.03, 76.67), (30.92, 76.67), (30.92, 74.91)

Comment: Or somewhere between the 2 above answers :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returned staticmap always has the same size(640x480).

So all you have to do when you use this tool is to set the site of the map inside the tool to the same size.

Then you'll be able to retrieve the bounds of the map inside the tool, which will be the same for the staticmap.

for a convenient usage run this inside the console when you use the wizard:

```
document.getElementById('map').style.cssText='width:640px;height:480px;left:'+
     ((document.body.offsetWidth-640)/2)+'px';
google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('staticMapButton'),
  'click',
  function(){
  prompt('bounds',map.getBounds().toString());
 });
```

you'll be prompted with the bounds now when you click the staticMap-button